# Representation of data record for an employee (generic method vs design pattern)

Tags: object-oriented, design-patterns, generics, kotlin

preface: I have a part of my code that is repeated more than once and I want to create a generic method or follow a design pattern to make the code cleaner.

**What I'm trying to achieve is:**

- I have a JSON array each array represents a different type of employee.
- I want to sort them by `joiningDate` then convert each List to JSON again then send them to the server.

this following class represents data record for an employee.
`records` denotes the data and it's in JSON format.
I parse the records data depending on the `employeeType`

```
data class EmployeeRecord(
    val recordId: Long?,
    val employeeType: EmployeeType,
    val records: String)
```

This is the employee type class

```
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = false)
enum class EmployeeType(val role: String) {
    CEO("CEO"),
    CTO("CTO"),
    Accountant("Accountant"),
    Developer("Developer");

    companion object {
        val tierOneTypes: List<EmployeeType>
            get() = listOf(
                Developer,
                Accountant
            )

        val tierTwoTypes: List<EmployeeType>
            get() = listOf(
                CEO,
                CTO
            )
    }
}
```

this is the employee types

```
sealed class EmployeeDataRecord(open val employeeType: EmployeeType)

@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
internal data class CeoData(
    @Json(name = "JoiningDate") val joiningDate: Long,
    @Json(name = "NumberOfBranches") val numberOfBranches: Int,
    @Json(name = "Address") val address: String,
    @Json(name = "Salary") val salary: Long
) : EmployeeDataRecord(EmployeeType.CEO) {
    companion object {

        fun create(
            joiningDate: Long,
            numberOfBranches: Int,
            address: String,
            salary: Long
        ): CeoData {

            return CeoData(
                joiningDate = joiningDate,
                numberOfBranches = numberOfBranches,
                address = address,
                salary = salary
            )
        }
    }
}

@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
internal data class CtoData(
    @Json(name = "HiringDate") val joiningDate: Long,
    @Json(name = "NumberOfTeams") val numberOfTeams: Int,
    @Json(name = "Address") val address: String,
    @Json(name = "Salary") val salary: Long
) : EmployeeDataRecord(EmployeeType.CTO) {
    companion object {

        fun create(
            joiningDate: Long,
            numberOfTeams: Int,
            address: String,
            salary: Long
        ): CtoData {

            return CtoData(
                joiningDate = joiningDate,
                numberOfTeams = numberOfTeams,
                address = address,
                salary = salary
            )
        }
    }
}

@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
internal data class AccountantData(
    @Json(name = "JoiningDate") val joiningDate: Long,
    @Json(name = "Address") val address: String,
    @Json(name = "Salary") val salary: Long
) : EmployeeDataRecord(EmployeeType.Accountant) {
    companion object {

        fun create(
            joiningDate: Long,
            address: String,
            salary: Long
        ): AccountantData {

            return AccountantData(
                joiningDate = joiningDate,
                address = address,
                salary = salary
            )
        }
    }
}

@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
internal data class DeveloperData(
    @Json(name = "JoiningDate") val joiningDate: Long,
    @Json(name = "TeamName") val teamName: String,
    @Json(name = "Address") val address: String,
    @Json(name = "Salary") val salary: Long
) : EmployeeDataRecord(EmployeeType.Developer) {
    companion object {

        fun create(
            joiningDate: Long,
            teamName: String,
            address: String,
            salary: Long
        ): DeveloperData {

            return DeveloperData(
                joiningDate = joiningDate,
                teamName = teamName,
                address = address,
                salary = salary
            )
        }
    }
}
```

here is the function that has the repeated code; as you can see `createTierOneData` and `createTierTwoData` have the same logic and it's repeated

```
class DataTest {

    private fun <T> listAdapter(modelClass: Class<T>): JsonAdapter<List<T>> {
        val type = Types.newParameterizedType(List::class.java, modelClass)
        return moshi.adapter(type)
    }


    private fun createTierOneData(employeeRecords: List<EmployeeRecord>):
            Pair<List<ServerAData>, List<ServerBData>> {
        val serverADataList = mutableListOf<ServerAData>()
        val serverBDataList = mutableListOf<ServerBData>()

        val accountantDataList = mutableListOf<AccountantData>()
        val developerDataList = mutableListOf<DeveloperData>()

        employeeRecords.forEach {
            if (it.employeeType in EmployeeType.tierOneTypes) {
                when (it.employeeType) {
                    EmployeeType.Accountant -> listAdapter(AccountantData::class.java).fromJson(
                        it.records
                    )?.let { records -> accountantDataList.addAll(records) }

                    EmployeeType.Developer -> listAdapter(DeveloperData::class.java).fromJson(
                        it.records
                    )?.let { records -> developerDataList.addAll(records) }

                }
            }
        }

        if (accountantDataList.isNotEmpty()) {
            if (accountantDataList.size > 1) {
                accountantDataList.sortBy { it.joiningDate }
            }

            val serverAData = ServerAData(
                EmployeeType.Accountant,
                listAdapter(AccountantData::class.java).toJson(accountantDataList)
            )
            val serverBData = ServerBData(
                EmployeeType.Developer, developerDataList.size,
                159025890000
            )

            serverADataList.add(serverAData)
            serverBDataList.add(serverBData)
        }

        if (developerDataList.isNotEmpty()) {
            if (developerDataList.size > 1) {
                developerDataList.sortBy { it.joiningDate }
            }

            val serverAData = ServerAData(
                EmployeeType.Developer,
                listAdapter(DeveloperData::class.java).toJson(developerDataList)
            )
            val serverBData = ServerBData(
                EmployeeType.Developer, developerDataList.size,
                159025890000
            )

            serverADataList.add(serverAData)
            serverBDataList.add(serverBData)
        }

        return Pair(serverADataList, serverBDataList)

    }

    private fun createTierTwoData(employeeRecords: List<EmployeeRecord>):
            Pair<List<ServerAData>, List<ServerBData>> {
        val serverADataList = mutableListOf<ServerAData>()
        val serverBDataList = mutableListOf<ServerBData>()

        val ctoDataList = mutableListOf<CtoData>()
        val ceoDataList = mutableListOf<CeoData>()

        employeeRecords.forEach {
            if (it.employeeType in EmployeeType.tierTwoTypes) {
                when (it.employeeType) {
                    EmployeeType.CTO -> listAdapter(CtoData::class.java).fromJson(
                        it.records
                    )?.let { records -> ctoDataList.addAll(records) }

                    EmployeeType.CEO -> listAdapter(CeoData::class.java).fromJson(
                        it.records
                    )?.let { records -> ceoDataList.addAll(records) }

                }
            }
        }

        if (ctoDataList.isNotEmpty()) {
            if (ctoDataList.size > 1) {
                ctoDataList.sortBy { it.joiningDate }
            }

            val serverAData = ServerAData(
                EmployeeType.CTO,
                listAdapter(CtoData::class.java).toJson(ctoDataList)
            )
            val serverBData = ServerBData(
                EmployeeType.CTO, ctoDataList.size,
                159025890000
            )

            serverADataList.add(serverAData)
            serverBDataList.add(serverBData)
        }

        if (ceoDataList.isNotEmpty()) {
            if (ceoDataList.size > 1) {
                ceoDataList.sortBy { it.joiningDate }
            }

            val serverAData = ServerAData(
                EmployeeType.CEO,
                listAdapter(CeoData::class.java).toJson(ceoDataList)
            )
            val serverBData = ServerBData(
                EmployeeType.CEO, ceoDataList.size,
                159025890000
            )

            serverADataList.add(serverAData)
            serverBDataList.add(serverBData)
        }

        return Pair(serverADataList, serverBDataList)

    }

}
```

and finally here are the ServersData classes

```
data class ServerAData(
    val type: EmployeeType,
    val dataRecord: String
)

data class ServerBData(
    val type: EmployeeType,
    val numberOfDataRecord: Int,
    val hiringDate: Long
)
```

so I am trying to find a way to refactor `createTierOneData` and `createTierTwoData` to apply DRY. I tried to make a generic function and I failed to do it properly.
is there an approach to make these methods generic?

or if you can guide me to a design pattern that I can apply here that would be great.

Comment: @Tenfour04 the point here is the logic is the same, for each list I have to check if is not empty then sort it the construct two objects. so I want to remove this repeated code or do it in a smarter way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd add the data class type to the enum entries (or alternatively you could put these in a global map).

```
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = false)
enum class EmployeeType(val role: String, val dataType: Class<out EmployeeDataRecord>) {
    CEO("CEO", CeoData::class.java),
    CTO("CTO", CtoData::class.java),
    Accountant("Accountant", AccountantData::class.java),
    Developer("Developer", DeveloperData::class.java);

    companion object {
        //...
    }
}
```

Since we're using covariant Class type, update the parameter for `listAdapter()` as well:

```
private fun <T> listAdapter(modelClass: Class<out T>): JsonAdapter<List<T>> {
```

Also, you are sorting all the data types by `joiningDate`, so it would help to make that a member of the super class:

```
sealed class EmployeeDataRecord(open val employeeType: EmployeeType){
    abstract val joiningDate: Long
}

@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
internal data class CeoData(
    @Json(name = "JoiningDate") override val joiningDate: Long,
    @Json(name = "NumberOfBranches") val numberOfBranches: Int,
    @Json(name = "Address") val address: String,
    @Json(name = "Salary") val salary: Long
) : EmployeeDataRecord(EmployeeType.CEO) { 
    //...
}
//etc.
```

Then you can add a parameter for a list of the types to process. When you call this function you can pass `EmployeeType.tierOneTypes` or `EmployeeType.tierTwoTypes`. This makes it flexible if you modify the input types. You can loop through this list (even though it's just a list of two) since you're doing the same thing to both input types. But you could change it to a list of any size and this function would still work.

To process the input, you could set up MutableLists and `forEach` like you're already doing, but it's more concise (and easier to read) to use `associateWith` and `flatMap`.

```
private fun createData(employeeRecords: List<EmployeeRecord>, typesToProcess: Iterable<EmployeeType>):
        Pair<List<ServerAData>, List<ServerBData>> {

    val employeeDataListsByType = typesToProcess.associateWith { type ->
        employeeRecords.filter { it.employeeType == type }
            .flatmap { listAdapter(type.dataType).fromJson(it.records) ?: emptyList() }
            .sortedBy(EmployeeDataRecord::joiningDate)
    }

    val serverADataList = employeeDataListsByType.mapNotNull { (type, list) ->
        if (list.isEmpty())
            null
        else
            ServerAData(type, listAdapter(type.dataType).toJson(list))
    }

    val serverBDataList = employeeDataListsByType.mapNotNull { (type, list) ->
        if (list.isEmpty())
            null
        else
            ServerBData(type, list.size, 159025890000)
    }

    return Pair(serverADataList, serverBDataList)

}
```

Depending on the size of your data, it might be more efficient to insert `.toSequence()` before the `filter` call, and then add `.toList()` after the `sortedBy` call

I didn't test this so I might have a few syntax errors.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I like what you did with the emum ```EmployeeType``` the only thing that didn't work out for me is that I want the map to contain the value of the sub data type, not the super data type. for example, the map is of type ```<EmployeeType, List<EmployeeDataRecord>>```, but I want it to be ```<EmployeeType, List<CeoData>>```,  because when I try to create ServerAData the listAdapter doesn't work because it expects subtype. I get an error that ```toJson``` expects `Nothing`

Comment: Try changing the type of the `modelClass` parameter of `listAdapter()` to `Class<out T>`.